# jquery.validatior.addMethod valid pattern with a space for email

Tags: javascript, regex, ecmascript-6, jquery-plugins

I need to check email text before save it.

I want to fill in multiple email and seperate by **";"** with following formats:

- **without a space** "nicola@gmail.com;linda@gmail.com"  (I succeed)
- **with a space** "nicola@gmail.com; linda@gmail.com"
- **with mutiple spaces** "nicola@gmail.com;    linda@gmail.com"

And I cannot use **type "email"** because Edge don't support, so I back to use a standard **"text" input**.

```js
$.validator.addMethod("pattern", function(value, element, param) {
 if (this.optional(element)) {
  return true;
 }
 if (typeof param === "string") {
  param = new RegExp(param);
 }
 return param.test(value);
    }, "Invalid format");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery-validation@1.17.0/dist/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<div class="form-data-field">
         <label class="fld">email</label>
         <input class="content" type="text" name="email" data-formfield="Email" maxlength="150" 
         pattern="^(([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)@([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)\.([a-zA-Z]{2,5}){1,25})+([;.](([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)@([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)\.([a-zA-Z]{2,5}){1,25})+)*$|^NC$" />
        </div>
```

Comment: I would suggest removing all white space and then simply splitting by ";"

Comment: You can't use the Email type with any browser because it won't let the user put in text in the wanted format...

Comment: Honestly, from an UX perspective, it would be much better to have a list of fields to fill, or a + button for adding a new email.

Comment: ...Or use something like https://bootstrap-tagsinput.github.io/bootstrap-tagsinput/examples/

Comment: Word of warning: Valid emails addresses can be in some VERY weird formats: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address#Examples -- If this code is for simple/personal use then fair enough, but I would not advise using complex regex like this for arbitrary real world data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I add `\s*` after `[;]` in pattern, and it works well

```
pattern="^(([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)@([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)\.([a-zA-Z]{2,5}){1,25})+([;]\s*(([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)@([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)\.([a-zA-Z]{2,5}){1,25})+)*$|^NC$"
```